# Hearth Protection

Tags: fireplace, hearth

Looking for some kind of protective mat for the area in front of this wood burning fireplace. Both to keep it clean for the 9 months we aren't using it and to protect it from heat/embers. It's only about 16" deep and has a radius curve. Hard to find precut item that would fit here. Is there another material that I can buy that is safe and I can cut to size?[image]

Answer (score 1):

We use a tin garage-floor drip pan in front of our wood burning stove. It won't be curved to fit your hearth but you could use tin snips to cut it to size to fit your opening, and notch it to fit perfectly.

[image]

Comment: Would probably need to file it to eliminate the sharp edges from the snipping

Comment: A bit of blood letting does not hurt the people watching usually.